# stata15 dyndoc: markdown table

Tags: markdown, stata

I've finally got the update for Stata 15, and one of the things I was excited about is the new functionality for dynamic documents. Although, I followed the steps described in the [official stata tutorial](https://www.stata.com/new-in-stata/markdown/), I was quickly disappointed when the html file dyndoc created failed to sparse the regression table. Here's what I did in the txt file:

```
~~~~
<<dd_do>>
webuse auto, clear
<</dd_do>>
~~~~

~~~~
<<dd_do: quietly>>
reg mpg weight
estimates store small
<</dd_do>>
~~~~

~~~~
<<dd_do:nocommand>>
_coef_table, markdown
<</dd_do>>
~~~~
```

Since this has failed I've also tried the approach [described here](https://huapeng01016.github.io/baltimore_2017/table.html):

```
~~~~
<<dd_do:nocommand>>
estimates table small, b(%7.4f) se(%7.4f) stats(N r2_a) markdown
<</dd_do>>
~~~~
```

This is how I sparse the txt with dyndoc:

```
dyndoc "`path'\auto.txt", saving(`path'\auto.html) replace
```

The results in the html file look like this:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

I am running Stata SE 15.1 on Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed, in case someone is looking at this. The problem was adding the `~~~~` as a wrapper around the code snippet. As the help file explains [(p.177)](https://www.stata.com/manuals/p.pdf), the tildes are used to mark the parts which should be displayed as plain text. The correct code for the regression table is:

```
~~~~
<<dd_do>>
webuse auto, clear
<</dd_do>>
~~~~

<<dd_do: quietly>>
reg mpg weight
estimates store small
<</dd_do>>

<<dd_do:nocommand>>
_coef_table, markdown
<</dd_do>>
```